# how to create rotating compass view similar to the iPhone crop/rotate image control

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to create a rotating compass wheel view similar to the iPhone crop/rotate image control like in the demo image below, all I want is the graduated ruler that can be controlled by swiping , if anyone knows a library or a component that could help doing this in iOS using objective-c.
thank you in advance 
[the demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN4Mu.jpg)